# Visual Studio hangs up on adding images in local root folder Resources?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, background-image, xamarin.forms

After adding images in the local root folder (Resources), Visual Studio hangs up completely. I am not able to see the added images in the Visual studio under the Resource folder. Even though i restarted the visual studio after adding the images in the local root folder, it completely gets stuck or images are not found under the particular folder path. Can anyone suggest or give me any ideas on why am i getting this problem and solution for it. Advance thanks for those had taken their interest in solving my problem.

Comment: Try adding them directly to the folder. Then run your VS and lets see if it works. What about the size of the images? Are they so big?

Comment: They aren't big, i tried adding them into the folder directly, the same thing happens visual studio gets hang up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and investigated the problem in detail.
**There is a bug in the Xamarin-VS-Integration-SW.**
You have to edit the .csproj-file manually.
**Short description:**
- Close VS
- Copy the new file manually in the resource-folder
- Edit the .csproj file with editor
- Add a new entry for the new file in the .csproj-file
- Save ad close the .csproj-file
- Start VS and load the project
- Done!

Further also **change the name of a resource manually** (as VS also hangs, if you do it in the VS solution-/project-manager).

**You can find all details in my posting here:**
[Details to bug (have a look at the attached .pdf)](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41844/my-findings-after-test-if-the-newest-xamarin-vs-integration-software#latest)
I further also have posted the bug on the official release-thread and filled a bug in Bugzilla:
[Filled bug in Xamarin Buzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30968)